# "within the context" of a workshop - synonyms

Tags: synonyms

For the acknowledgements of my thesis, I need to thank my advisors. They invited me to a workshop where we worked on my topic for one week. Now I would somehow want to write the following:

*The author is greatly indepted to ... and ... for suggesting this problem, several valuable comments, and many enlightening discussions, also "within the context of" the workshop in ..., where a non-negligible part of the ideas emerged.*

I am grateful for any suggestions (not only for the synonym). Thank you!

Comment: why not "also for the workshop"? What is "within the context of the workshop" supposed to mean in this sentence anyhow? Do you want to refer to specific contents of the workshop or the value of it? Then just add an adjective fruitful/productive/creative...

Comment: I used this "within the context of" because I wanted to say that I am in particular also grateful for the valuable comments, the enlightening discussions during the workshop. I added this ", also .." to avoid one further comma/and, because without this it would be like this:
" ... for suggesting this problem, several valuable comments, many enlightening discussions, and the fruitful workshop, where a non-negligible part of the ideas emerged."
It would be a good idea to also thank for the workshop on its own (so basically for the invitation) and not only the contents. But I don't know how..

Comment: How about **...discussions as well as the _adjective_ workshop...**

Comment: So you would suggest "The author is greatly indepted to ... and ... for suggesting this problem, several valuable comments, many enlightening discussions as well as the fruitful workshop in ..., where where a non-negligible part of the ideas emerged."?
Sounds good for me, but as I am not a native speaker, I don't know exactly whether it is correct and "good-sounding". But if you approve, I think is how I will write it. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

## During

> "also during the workshop"

**During**

Meaning: "from the beginning to the end..." [cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/during)

You will need to rewrite part of your sentence for the change in word forms, something like this: -

**Edit**:
Given your recent comments, I think this would work best: -

> The author is greatly indebted to ... and ... for suggesting this problem and providing several valuable comments. The author is especially grateful for the many enlightening discussions (during the workshop) which facilitated the emergence of several key ideas.

*What I have done:*

I have made the passage into two sentences as I felt it was getting rather long. I have used the word 'especially' which is used to single out a key thing above all others (in this case, from your comments the sense I gain is that the workshop and the ideas that came out of it were especially valuable). I have said that the ideas were facilitated by the discussions which I think is a truer reflection of what you were intending to say.

I have moved away from the concept of quantifying the ideas relative to the whole number of ideas, and instead focussed on the significance that the 'quality' of the ideas brought to you. I hope I have understood you well, from the question and your comments. I think the above works quite well.

Do Let me know if you have any questions or if I have made any incorrect assumptions.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question and the resulting sentence would not be grammatical.

Comment: Still wouldn't match the first part of the sentence.

Comment: @Helmar see above, thanks for pointing it out, the answer is better for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So @Helmar, I think that it would match the first part of the sentence (why not?) but it could be that there might be "better solutions".
Could you tell me why you omitted the comma? I thought that the comma is omitted only when the sentence wouldn't make sense without this part after the comma. However, I could just omit "where a non-negligible part of the ideas emerged" without changing the meaning of the sentence, couldn't I? So why don't you put a comma there? (I am not that sure about how this rule works, so sorry for the stupid question..)

Comment: @user136457 i've edited my answer a little to make the use clearer in light of your whole sentence, and I've also exchanged the word 'part' for 'number' - please let me know if anything about it is unclear etc.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and the edits. 
I am not completely sure about number, though. The reason why I used "part" is that I wanted to say something like "proportion", "fraction". So we had for example 100 ideas, and 10 out of them came from the workshop. Does it then really make sense to write "a non-negligible number"? Wouldn't it then make more sense to just write "numerous ideas" or something like that? I do not know, maybe it fits perfectly, but when I "directly" translate it to my mother tongue it somehow sounds wrong. But if you think 'number' fits the context, then it's great.

Comment: OK I think we are there now. Having understood your comments. Hope it helps as I have to dissapear now for a bit. Let me know if you have any questions etc. and I'll do my best to reply tomorrow. @user136457

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I really like it and I am quite sure you understood me correctly. I think this is what I will write. Thanks a lot. 
(At the moment, I am a little bit unsure about the two sentence that start both with the same words "The author". Is this okay or should one avoid it?)